# Integrating a functional of an InterpolatingFunction

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

It is straightforward to `Integrate` an `InterpolatingFunction`. However, even for a simple functional of an `InterpolatingFunction`,  `Integrate` returns unevaluated.

```
ifun1 =
  First[
    u /. 
      NDSolve[
        {u''[t] + u[t] == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 1},
        u,
        {t, 0, π}
      ]
  ]

Integrate[ifun1[t], {t, 0, π}]
Integrate[2*ifun1[t], {t, 0, π}]
```

The former `Integrate` returns a `Real`, the latter, the expression unevaluated.

How can the second integral be evaluated symbolically? (In my non-MWE, *symbolically* is important because the solution to my PDE has two arguments, over only one of which I would like to integrate, so `NIntegrate` will not work.) The solution should apply to more-complicated functionals, too (e.g. `2*t*ifun1[t]`). If a solution applies only to functionals that are restricted to a certain family, such as "linear," it would still be helpful.

Comment: Use `NIntegrate`

Comment: @rasher, I want to avoid this because my non-MWE is a PDE solution with two arguments and I want to integrate over only one of them. `NIntegrate` can't do that, in my experience (because the other argument is non-numerical). (updated my question)

Comment: You can use `FunctionInterpolation[2*ifun1[t], {t, 0, π}]` to get the resulting `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: I am not sure why it does not work. I think Integrate does not know if `c*ifun1[t]` will converge. Even if `c` is constant. Only when `c=1` it will do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should know that your first `Integrate` is numerically evaluated (so Mathematica calls `NIntegrate` on your interpolation function anyway). On the second I don't know why Mathematica doesn't call `NIntegrate` immediately but explicitly using `NIntegrate` yields a result.

In any case, this is building on your comment that you have a function with two arguments and you want to integrate over one and get a result as a function of the other. In my opinion b.gatessucks is spot on in that you need to use `FunctionInterpolation`.

Here's a random set of points:

```
points = MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #1[[3]] + #2} &, {Flatten[
     Array[{Sequence@##, Sin[Times@##]} &, {20, 20}], 1], 
    RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 400]}];
```

and here's an interpolation of the points:

```
f = Interpolation[points];
```

Now you can do whatever you want in the integrand over one of the arguments. `FunctionInterpolation` will evaluate the integral numerically at some points of your specified domain and create a function :

```
g = FunctionInterpolation[

  Integrate[2*f[t, y] - f[t, y]^2 + t Cos[f[t, y]], {t, 0, π}]
  ,
  {y, 1., 20.}
  ]
```

that behaves like any interpolating function. But note that "symbolically" and `Interpolation` are quite incompatible notions.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I'm in the process of testing this for my case. I'll report back asap.

Comment: This works great, thanks! I ended up doing the `FunctionInterpolation` *before* the integration, which seemed to be more straight-forward to implement when writing function. I don't know that there are any significant advantages to switching the order, though (your order works just fine).

Comment: Hey, glad it worked! It is pretty much the same idea when you call `ParametricNDSolve`. Mathematica solves for certain values in the range of the parameter and creates a function interpolation of the solutino w.r.t. the parameter

Comment: @gpap, although your approach certainly is useful, it can reduce the accuracy of the answer substantially.

Comment: @bbgodfrey yeah, I agree - but part of that (in the specific problem at least) would be due to how the original interpolation function is calculated which you'd have *some* control over. I don't see how else one could do this unless one created a set of points and *then* interpolated...?