# Non-rectilinear integration of InterpolatingFunction

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, interpolation, coordinate-transformation

**Bug introduced in 7 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

[CASE:3487737]

---

I have a 2-d array that I would like to resample into a different coordinate system and integrate along one of the new coordinates. Here is an example array:

```
arr = GaussianMatrix[50]*ArrayPad[DiamondMatrix[5], {45, 45}, DiamondMatrix[5]];
ArrayPlot[arr, PixelConstrained -> {1, 1}]
```

> [image: example array]

To accomplish the resampling, I interpolate:

```
if = ListInterpolation[arr, InterpolationOrder -> 1, Method -> "Hermite"];
DensityPlot[if[x, y], {x, 1, 101}, {y, 1, 101},
 PlotPoints -> 101, MaxRecursion -> 0
]
```

> [image: interpolated array]

(The interpolation is good, even if the `DensityPlot` looks a bit ragged.)

It is easy to integrate the `InterpolationFunction` along one of the "natural" coordinates (i.e., without resampling):

```
int = Integrate[if[x, y], {x, 40, 60}]
(* -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 101.}}, <>][y] *)
Plot[int, {y, 1, 101}]
```

> [image: integrated along x]

However, any change (even a trivial one) to the coordinate system causes `Integrate` to produce a nonsensical answer:

```
Integrate[if[(x + y)/2, y], {x, 40, 60}]
(* -> 20 InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 101.}, {1., 101.}}, <>][(x + y)/2, y] *)

Integrate[if[x + 1, y], {x, 40, 60}]
(* -> 20 InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 101.}, {1., 101.}}, <>][1 + x, y] *)
```

As the answers to [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/integrating-a-functional-of-an-interpolatingfunction) propose, we could work around this by re-interpolating the resampled function using `FunctionInterpolation` before integrating. This would work:

```
if2 = FunctionInterpolation[
 if[(x + y)/2, y], {x, 1, 101}, {y, 1, 101},
 InterpolationOrder -> 1
];
int2 = Integrate[if2[x, y], {x, 40, 60}]
(* -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 101.}}, <>][y] *)
```

The problem is that `FunctionInterpolation` does a very poor job of sampling the function unless `InterpolationPoints` is far above twice the "resolution" of the underlying interpolation. In this case over 500(!) `InterpolationPoints` are needed to get a reasonable reproduction of the resampled function:

- Default (11) `InterpolationPoints`

  > [image: resampled with 11 InterpolationPoints]
- 101 `InterpolationPoints`

  > [image: resampled with 101 InterpolationPoints]
- 301 `InterpolationPoints`

  > [image: resampled with 301 InterpolationPoints]
- and so on...

As you can see, the result is aliased to the point of uselessness until `InterpolationPoints` gets really high. With so many sampling points required, this is not an intelligent way to proceed, and there is no benefit to using `FunctionInterpolation` and `Integrate` over tabulating the function values at high resolution and summing over the resulting array.

So:

- Is it possible to construct the resampled `InterpolatingFunction` from the original `ListInterpolation` more intelligently, to obtain better results than those given by `FunctionInterpolation`? Or,
- Can `Integrate` be made to behave more reasonably when given the integration directly?

Comment: Are the changes in coordinates always linear/affine?

Comment: @MichaelE2 no, the coordinate change I'm really interested in isn't. However it isn't too far from it: it transforms a skewed trapezoid into a rectangle. But if you have a solution that works well only for affine transformations, I'd still be interested to see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was not intended to be a self-answered question, but I found some methods that work well enough.

#### Method 1: `NDSolve`

I had been focused on doing the resampling *before* the integration, and could not get `NDSolve` to do that (because it objects that the input is not a differential equation, which is indeed true). But it can do both at the same time:

```
res = NDSolveValue[{
    Derivative[1, 0][t][x, y] == if[(x + y)/2, y], t[1, y] == if[1, y]
   }, t, {x, 1, 101}, {y, 1, 101},
   MaxStepSize -> {2, 0.5}, InterpolationOrder -> All
  ]
(* -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 101.}, {1., 101.}}, <>] *)

ByteCount[res] (* -> 202664 *)
```

The result seems (mostly) reasonable:

```
Plot[res[60, y] - res[40, y], {y, 1, 101}]
```

> [image: Plot of integral produced by NDSolve]

Advantages:

- *Mathematica* does all the work by itself
- Intelligent sampling and construction of `InterpolatingFunction`s--copes well with nonuniform (e.g. polar) resamplings (at least in principle)
- Can obtain definite integrals directly from the result without further processing

Disadvantages:

- Can't use it for resampling without integration
- Does not properly capture the structure of the original interpolation without setting `MaxStepSize` on the order of the feature length--note the shape of the troughs between peaks in the above figure. This is less of a problem for `InterpolationOrder` of the original `ListInterpolation` higher than 1, but that introduces artefacts into the resampled image that do not correspond to any feature of the original, and incorrectly rounds out the peaks and troughs of the integral.
- Due to small `MaxStepSize`, it produces a larger result, and more slowly, than seemingly it could. I admit I'm not very familiar with `NDSolve` `Method` tuning, but nothing I tried yielded any progress toward a smaller, quicker, and/or more accurate result.

#### Method 2: gridding and reinterpolation

Resampling over a grid and then interpolating with `ListInterpolation` is much faster than `FunctionInterpolation` and requires fewer sampling points for a reasonable result. The main problem is fighting against the strange interpretation of `Listable` that `InterpolatingFunction` seems to have, which would be more of a nuisance for interpolations in greater than two dimensions.

```
pts = Compile[{}, 
  Table[{(x + y)/2, y}, {x, 1., 101., 2.}, {y, 1., 101., 0.5}]
 ][];
resampled = if @@@ Transpose[pts, {1, 3, 2}]; (* unpacks, unfortunately *)

if2 = ListInterpolation[
  resampled, {{1, 101}, {1, 101}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1, Method -> "Hermite"
 ]
(* -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 101.}, {1., 101.}}, <>] *)

ByteCount[if2] (* -> 167568 *)
```

This can be integrated normally and the result is a little better than that produced by `NDSolve`:

```
int2 = Integrate[if2[x, y], {x, 40, 60}]
(* -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 101.}}, <>][y] *)
Plot[int2, {y, 1, 101}]
```

> [image: Result produced by Integrate from ListInterpolate over a grid]

Advantages:

- Simple and direct method
- About twice as fast as `NDSolve`, and *much faster* than `FunctionInterpolation`, while being more accurate than either with fewer sampling points (in this case)

Disadvantages:

- Won't cope well with nonuniform resampling due to fixed grid spacing
- `InterpolatingFunction` is not conveniently `Listable`, requiring a `Transpose` and `Apply` to produce the 2-d resampling. Ignoring listability to take the samples point-by-point is many times slower, so this is necessary.

---

The second method works well enough for my real application, but I would like to be able to do a better job with `NDSolve`. Does anyone have suggestions on how the sampling can be optimized with the latter, to capture the peaks and troughs successfully (without rounding) while spending fewer samples on the smooth sides of the peaks?

Comment: I find it a bit annoying that this sort of gymnastics has to be done for something this simple…

Comment: @J.M. yes, me too. I have reported the misbehavior of `Integrate` as a bug today, and suggested that a desired result would be more like that produced by `NDSolve`.