# Irregular image binning

Tags: image-processing

Is there a good way to "bin" image data, which is analogous to hardware binning of a detector array? I'd like it to treat image data such that multiple values are averaged to form one mega-sample, giving the impression of a coarser detector array.

Here's an try with `ImageResize` and `ArrayResample`:

```
Module[{data, fn},
 data = ImageData@ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"];
 fn = ImageResize[#, Scaled[5], Resampling -> "Nearest"] &;
 fn@Image@ArrayResample[data, Scaled[0.2], Resampling -> "Nearest"]]
```

[image]

I would like to set the bins with more flexibility, for instance, binning in a single dimension.

Comment: to literally simulate hardware  binning you want to `Partiton` the image and take the mean of each subset.

Comment: ImagePartition / NeatExamples?

Comment: It is related to my question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101678/non-rectilinear-integration-of-interpolatingfunction

Answer (score 3):

```
binPixels[img_, binSize_] /;Length[binSize]==2 :=
   Module[{pieces, avg},
          pieces = ImagePartition[img, {{1, binSize[[1]]}, {1, binSize[[2]]}}];
          avg = Mean@Flatten@ImageData[#] &;
          ImageAssemble@Table[Image@Array[(avg@pieces[[i, j]]) &, Reverse@binSize],
                              {i, First@Dimensions[pieces]}, {j, Last@Dimensions[pieces]}]]

With[{img = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"]},
      binPixels[img, {5, 10}]]
```

[image]

```
ImageDimensions[%]
(* {515, 520} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

ColorQuantize reduces the number of "colors" (in this case, of grey scale values), effectively binning pixels of the image.

```
ColorQuantize[ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"], 3]
```

[image]

Use the Dithering->False option if you want the resulting image to *not* use dithering.

Comment: Doesn't fit my application, but interesting. I wasn't aware of `ColorQuantize`.

Comment: binning actually can *increase* the number of colors. Simple example if you take a 1-bit image and do 4 pixel binning you end up with 4 "colors" (that's exactly why its done in hardware you trade better dynamic range for lower resolution )

Comment: This is also what dithering is about... locally increasing the number of bins...

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageAssemble@
 Map[ColorQuantize[#, 1] &, ImagePartition[img, {10, 10}], {2}]
```

[image]

to illustrate the increased colors, suppose we start with bill's quantized image:

```
qimg = ColorQuantize[
   ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"], 3];
Union@Flatten@ImageData[qimg] // Length
```

> 3

then bin it..

```
binned = ImageAssemble@
   Map[ColorQuantize[#, 1] &, ImagePartition[qimg, {4, 4}], {2}];
Union@Flatten@ImageData[binned] // Length
```

> 95

Comment: For some reason, the bins are always square ... I get the same for {1,10} and {10,10}.

Comment: with this approach each rectangular bin is replaced with a uniform bin of the same shape so the overall aspect ratio doesn't change. Try `{10, 40}` and I think you should see.

Comment: I see what you mean. Looks like the partition spec is interpreted as {min,max} instead of {dx,dy}, as I had assumed, thinking in terms of pixel binning.